# Expired Media Links

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Anybody knows how to fix as issue with expired instagram media links ? 
Im parsing media and after a few days/weeks/hours the links are expired.
Maybe there is a way to use this links or fix somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it, in the instagram media api you can fetch the perma_link like https://www.instagram.com/p/Bt3QrphggBw/. Just add
https://www.instagram.com/p/Bt3QrphggBw/media/?size=m. It will redirect to the proper image url.

**EDIT 2021: This method is deprecated. Read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed) to learn how to use the new oEmbed Instagram API.**

Comment: This does not work if the account is private so it's not a good general solution.

Answer (score 0):

All of the media links generated by instagram have timestamp components in them, ie. those links have an expiration time (not sure exactly how much but all of the links expire after some time). The workaround is either to keep refreshing the links by calling instagram api or to store the images somewhere and use that link.

Comment: Even the media id is not valid after link expiration. So its impossible to refresh link of the media. And its abandoned to store the media(instagram rules)

Comment: I used instagram apis a while back for a project but don't remember media id's changing for the same media. Can you share any fresh media link which works as of now and which api you are using to query media from instagram?

Comment: I use mgp25/InstagramApi.
Working media url - https://instagram.fiev1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e931a0b8f3fb72e6b518beec9f4a73bf/5C7ED4C0/t51.2885-15/e35/43913347_1168016573355879_3345056674571553627_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTg5Mzc4MTEwMTAzNjMwMjgxMg%3D%3D.2

Comment: Ohhh this is a private API and not maintained by Instagram. I didnot know that. I will go through the API and post something if I come across anything that might be useful for you.

Comment: Yep. private, because public has less functionality (